# Angular - I need to assign a default value to my options

Tags: html, angular

```
<div class="name margen" *ngIf="!nomostrartema">Tema</div>
<select formControlName="temas" *ngIf="!nomostrartema" name="tema" [(ngModel)]="opcionTema" (change)="capturarTema()" style="width:120px">
    <option *ngFor="let temario of temas" [ngValue]="temario.id"
    [selected]="temario.NameTema">
     {{temario.NameTema}}</option>
</select>
```

I need to show a value by default, the problem is that these topics that are being displayed, have different ids and do not match, depending on the position of the options, I think that a good option would be to ask in the OnInit which element is stored. My question is the following as I do to link, that data of the controller in view to show that option of the theme according to the already stored

Attention! , there are no errors, in the data storage, only in the sample of these

Comment: can we have the code of your component which relevant to this template

Comment: Yes, If you can really have it I send you all the onInit...?